# how to connect the compiler masm32 to notepad++

Tags: assembly, notepad++, masm32

where download masm32 compiler? I've uploaded [here](http://www.masm32.com/masmdl.htm) but I can not understand how it implement(run/compiling) the project. where I can download just the compiler. how run first project, instance this

```
 
begin
 {Устанавливаем графический режим монитора 13h, 320x200, 256 цветов}
 asm
 mov  ax,0013h
 int  10h
 end;
 asm
 mov  ax,0A000h
 mov  es,ax
 {Рисуем - раз}
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*10+10],12
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*10+11],12
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*10+12],12
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*11+10],12
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*11+11],12
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*11+12],12
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*12+10],12
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*12+11],12
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*12+12],12
 {Рисуем - два}
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*100+100],1
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*101+101],2
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*102+102],3
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*103+103],4
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*104+104],5
 mov  byte ptr es:[320*105+105],6
 end;
 {Ожидаем нажатия клавиши}
 asm
 mov  ah,0
 int  16h
 end;
 {Устанавливаем текстовый режим монитора 03h, 80x25, 16 цветов текста и фона}
 asm
 mov  ax,0003h
 int  10h
 end;
end.
```

Please answer in detail

Comment: It looks like there's a help file included with the download. You should read that help file.

Comment: if i found be, i'm not ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely read that help file, and also, unless this is a snippet of code, you might want to do some more reading on assembly in general. Where are your sections? Moreover, why are you bothering with Mode 13h at all? MASM32 is often used for Windows assembly-language programming, yet you're mucking around directly with video modes. I haven't used Windows in years but I'm pretty sure most modern flavors of Windows won't be too happy if you do that.

There's a variety of graphics toolkits available in a number of languages that are far easier to work with than what you're doing. INT 10H in particular is sloooooow, and it's also not especially portable.

If this is for a course you're taking, you might want to ask your instructor for some hints on how to get this up and running.